# How to make an interactive plot with Shiny in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny

I am using a multi-file setup so I have both ui.r and server.r files. I am using the dataset below which looks at UFO sightings in different states/provinces in U.S./Canada in 2016.

```
        Date        Time  AM.PM Country       City  State   Shape
1   12/21/2016  7:15:00     PM  USA      Waynesboro   VA    Sphere
2   12/21/2016  12:00:00    AM  USA      Louisville   KY    Unknown
3   12/20/2016  10:30:00    PM  USA      Santa Rosa   CA    Sphere
4   12/20/2016  7:00:00     PM  USA      Fresno       CA    Circle
5   12/19/2016  9:53:00     PM  USA      Reymert      AZ    Circle
6   1/11/2016   8:15:00     PM  CANADA   Mississauga  ON    Circle
```

What I want to do is make a plot in my main panel which will display a plot that is able to show different data that the user selects by a widget on a side panel. I want to create a histogram that will have each possible shape of the UFO corresponding to a different bar on the x-axis and then the number of observations (for each of the UFO shapes) for the country that the user selected using the widget on the y-axis. I'm just having trouble on how to use ggplot to make the histogram with the Shiny aspects. Any help is appreciated!

UI file:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Exploring UFO Sightings"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("Country",
                        "Country to Display:",
                        choices = list("USA" = 'USA',
                                       "Canada" = 'CANADA'),
                        ),
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("ufoPlot")
        )
    )
))
```

Server file:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$ufoPlot <- renderPlot({

        ufo_data <- ufo_data_filter %>% filter(Country == input$country)
        #Not sure how to plot this
    })
})
```

Comment: You can put whatever ggplot code you want in the `renderPlot()` function. Do you know how to make a ggplot histogram outside of shiny? What exactly did you try? Where did you get stuck? This example uses ggplot: https://psyteachr.github.io/shiny-tutorials/01-first-app.html#26_Change_the_plot_colour

Comment: @MrFlick I tried this `shinyServer(function(input, output) { output$ufoPlot <- renderPlot({ ufo_data_filter <- filter(ufo_data, Country == input$Country) ggplot(ufo_data_filter, aes(x = Shape)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") }) })` and the app popped up in the window but I get an error that says I need to specify my y value but I thought if the y wasn't specified it would automatically default to the number of occurences. If not, how would I get it so the number of occurrences is the y value of the plot?

Comment: Just use `geom_bar()`, not `geom_bar(stat="identity")`. by using `stat="identity"` you are explicitly telling it *not* to use the number of occurrences. But this is really just a basic ggplot issue. It doesn't have anything to do with shiny. You should always test your plotting code outside of shiny first.